# Problem run of my project Flutter Java proxy problem

Tags: android, flutter

For first project Flutter wants run or build APK show me error ,  flutter doctor is all ok, proxy is off,  SDK Android is Android 31 and have more errors in `flutter.gradle` please help me

- flutter doctor is ok
- gradle in Android project worked properly
- proxy in setting off
- more errors in `flutter.gradle` file
- not support device connect (windows , chrome )

```
 C:\Users\hp\Videos\mightyfirebasechat\android>gradlew
Downloading https://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-6.1.1-all.zip

Exception in thread "main" java.net.SocketException: Network is unreachable: connect
        at java.base/sun.nio.ch.Net.connect0(Native Method)
        at java.base/sun.nio.ch.Net.connect(Net.java:579)
        at java.base/sun.nio.ch.Net.connect(Net.java:568)
        at java.base/sun.nio.ch.NioSocketImpl.connect(NioSocketImpl.java:588)
        at java.base/java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:633)
        at java.base/java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:583)
        at java.base/sun.net.NetworkClient.doConnect(NetworkClient.java:183)
        at java.base/sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.openServer(HttpClient.java:498)
        at java.base/sun.net.www.http.HttpClient$1.run(HttpClient.java:557)
        at java.base/sun.net.www.http.HttpClient$1.run(HttpClient.java:555)
        at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:569)
        at java.base/sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.privilegedOpenServer(HttpClient.java:554)
        at java.base/sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.openServer(HttpClient.java:598)
        at java.base/sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsClient.<init>(HttpsClient.java:266)
        at java.base/sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsClient.New(HttpsClient.java:380)
        at java.base/sun.net.www.protocol.https.AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.getNewHttpClient(AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.java:198)
        at java.base/sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.plainConnect0(HttpURLConnection.java:1263)
        at java.base/sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.plainConnect(HttpURLConnection.java:1128)
        at java.base/sun.net.www.protocol.https.AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.connect(AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.java:175)
        at java.base/sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream0(HttpURLConnection.java:1665)
        at java.base/sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream(HttpURLConnection.java:1589)
        at java.base/sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.getInputStream(HttpsURLConnectionImpl.java:224)
        at org.gradle.wrapper.Download.downloadInternal(Download.java:58)
        at org.gradle.wrapper.Download.download(Download.java:44)
        at org.gradle.wrapper.Install$1.call(Install.java:61)
        at org.gradle.wrapper.Install$1.call(Install.java:48)
        at org.gradle.wrapper.ExclusiveFileAccessManager.access(ExclusiveFileAccessManager.java:65)
        at org.gradle.wrapper.Install.createDist(Install.java:48)
        at org.gradle.wrapper.WrapperExecutor.execute(WrapperExecutor.java:128)
        at org.gradle.wrapper.GradleWrapperMain.main(GradleWrapperMain.java:61)
```

flutter -run verbose :

```
[ +222 ms] 
#0      throwToolExit (package:flutter_tools/src/base/common.dart:10:3)
#1      RunCommand.validateCommand (package:flutter_tools/src/commands/run.dart:465:7)
<asynchronous suspension>
#2      FlutterCommand.verifyThenRunCommand (package:flutter_tools/src/runner/flutter_command.dart:1248:5)
<asynchronous suspension>
#3      FlutterCommand.run.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter_tools/src/runner/flutter_command.dart:1140:27)
<asynchronous suspension>
#4      AppContext.run.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter_tools/src/base/context.dart:150:19)
<asynchronous suspension>
#5      CommandRunner.runCommand (package:args/command_runner.dart:209:13)
<asynchronous suspension>
#6      FlutterCommandRunner.runCommand.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter_tools/src/runner/flutter_command_runner.dart:288:9)
<asynchronous suspension>
#7      AppContext.run.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter_tools/src/base/context.dart:150:19)
<asynchronous suspension>
#8      FlutterCommandRunner.runCommand (package:flutter_tools/src/runner/flutter_command_runner.dart:236:5)
<asynchronous suspension>
#9      run.<anonymous closure>.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter_tools/runner.dart:62:9)
<asynchronous suspension>
#10     AppContext.run.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter_tools/src/base/context.dart:150:19)
<asynchronous suspension>
#11     main (package:flutter_tools/executable.dart:94:3)
<asynchronous suspension>

[ +353 ms] ensureAnalyticsSent: 268ms
[   +5 ms] Running shutdown hooks
[   +1 ms] Shutdown hooks complete
[   +4 ms] exiting with code 1
```

Comment: Having the same issue. Can't find resolution.

Answer (score -1):

Run the commands:

```
flutter clean
```

Followed by

```
flutter pub get
```

I usually do this when flutter does something unexpected, so give it a try.

Although, I think the problem has to do with android studio, so make sure you've followed the installation steps correctly.